# Javascript radio forma

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

данные не передаються с ajax в php файл как правильно передать их точнее определить положение радиобутонов?

```
var data13 = document.getElementById("work").value;

<input type="radio" name="hidd" id="hidd" value="0"> Скрыть 
   <input type="radio" name="hidd" id="hidd" value="1" checked> Не скрывать<br />
```

Answer (score 2):

Не может быть 2 одинаковых ID в одном документе:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="but1" class="ajax-send" value="0" />Скрыть
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="but1" class="ajax-send" value="1" checked />Не скрывать
</label>

<script>
$('.ajax-send').click(function(){
     var out = 'radio=' + $(this).val();
     $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'КУДА_СЛАТЬ_АЯКС.PHP', data: out });
});
</script>
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/BAEk5/

Answer (score 1):

```
data: $('#send_form').serialize(),
```

Использовал и никаких заморочек.

Comment: а если `<form></form>` нет в документе?

Comment: Ну в данном случае у меня есть форма.

Comment: Если нет формы можно обернуть в форму, например так:

 FormHelper:{
  getValuesFrom:function (query) {

   var result = $(query).wrap("<form/>").parent().serializeArray();
   $(query).unwrap();
   return result;
  }